# Which text sentiment analysis models have more than the 3 generic outputs?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, deep-learning, sentiment-analysis

I am an ug EE student working on my fyp. My fyp involves multimodal sentiment analysis. I was trying to implement the audio-specific portion of my fyp(which involves extracting audio, then extracting mel frequency co-efficients, plotting those co-efficients, also converting audio to speech, finally outputing the sentiment). I was having a problem, all of the python libraries for text sentiment analysis have functions that only output the 3(negative,positive,neutral). In my fyp I wanted a bigger variety(angry,happy,surprised,bored,neutral etc.)

My visual-specific portion of fyp has 7 emotions.

Anyways i also have to apply multimodal fusion at the end of this fyp but right now my question is that is there a function or model that outputs several sentiments?(not negative,positive,neutral)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.